# Roland UA-M10 not running properly

Tags: fedora, audio, alsa

Good evening everyone, I have a little and maybe difficult question.

But first i want to describe my environment: I'm using a Desktop-PC and a notebook with Fedora 24. In the past i bought some Beyerdynamics DT 880 and the seller recommended the sound card which name you can see in the title (Roland UA-M10).

I searched in the internet for drivers, installed all available alsa drivers on my Notebook (It was Fedora 23 back then) and hoped, that the sound card will at least work on my notebook. I went to the shop once again and tried to get it running. It worked somehow, but only with mp3 files, which doesn't makes sense to me. FLAC, ALAC or ACC files weren't played through the sound card.

My question is now, is there any other open-source driver that could possibly installed in any way?

The sound card is not in the official list from alsa for devices that are working with their drivers. Could anybody tell me, why mp3 files worked, but nothing else?

Faithfully, Alexander

Comment: Whether it is MP3 or other format it should not matter.  A sound card plays audio after decompression.  Since you are using alsa get a WAV (to make sure you are not dealing with containers and compression) and see the result of `aplay -vv file.wav`.  If that plays you're fine with drivers.  Also, what are you using to play the files? (`vlc`?, `mpv`? `mplayer`?)

Comment: @grochmal, i think i tried a WAV file as well, but only with VLC. In common, i used VLC, but also tried Amarok and SMPlayer. None of them worked except for MP3 files. Do you think it was more a problem with the decoder of the player? Would make sense... When i was at the shop i changed the decoder once, but don't ask me to what. 
I will definitely try to play a file like you said. That will be around the end of next week.

Comment: Do *not* install any ALSA drivers; they are already part of the kernel. (If you want to update drivers, you need to update the kernel.) If MP3 files work, then you do not have a driver problem.

Comment: @CL, i will try it with a fresh installed up to date Version of fedora 24. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i bought the soundcard today and noticed a very strange issue.
With aplayer the FLAC file wasn'n able to play. aplay only shows 100% (MAX) volume.
With WAV files it worked fine.
But Amarok was able to play the FLAC file. Now the strange issue.
I have a webm with only a sond track in it. But i can't play it.
But, if i play the FLAC in Amarok and then play at the same time the webm in the dragon player, the dragon player is able to play it.
If i close amarok then the webm plays fine till the end. 
I couldn't get it to run without this methode. Even with aplay. It just shows the MAX Volume.
WAV Files with Amarok isn't a problem either.
Does anybody has any type of solution for this or is this just a strange bug i discovered?
Another thing i discovered after it was, that if a file is playing with amarok and i run aplay at the same time 
with a for example WEBM or FLAC file, that it plays a horribly loud "scratch", which it doesn't if amarok doesn't play anything.

A second very strange thing is, that a can't play any AC3 files. I converted them to WAV or FLAC, but even amarok cant get it to run on the soundcard. I used ffmpeg for converting.

aplay prints this with a FLAC or WEBM File:

```
ALSA <-> PulseAudio PCM I/O Plugin"
Its setup is:
stream       : PLAYBACK
access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
format       : U8
subformat    : STD
channels     : 1
rate         : 8000
exact rate   : 8000 (8000/1)
msbits       : 8
buffer_size  : 4000
period_size  : 1000
period_time  : 125000
tstamp_mode  : NONE
tstamp_type  : GETTIMEOFDAY
period_step  : 1
avail_min    : 1000
period_event : 0
start_threshold  : 4000
stop_threshold   : 4000
silence_threshold: 0
silence_size : 0
boundary     : 9007199254740992000
##################################################+| MAX"
```

Chrome and Discord worked fine. Only firefox wasn't able to play any sound. Teamspeak was able too.

**EDIT**

I found a perfectly working solution for it.
Chrome did not work after a reboot so i decided to try to deactivate all other playback devices. I downloaded pavucontrol and deactivated them all. Everything works perfectly now. All Applications all formats and all files.